# Avoid indexing the keys in a Javascript array

Tags: javascript, array

I need a data structure to store feeds in columns into tabs.

So the pseudo structure would be:

```
First Tab : name (string)
    First column
        First feed : (url (str), type (str), limit (int))
        Second feed : (url (str), type (str), limit (int))
    Second column
        First feed : (url (str), type (str), limit (int))
        Second feed : (url (str), type (str), limit (int))
        Third feed : (url (str), type (str), limit (int))
Second Tab : name (string)
    First column
        First feed : (url (str), type (str), limit (int))
    Second column
        First feed : (url (str), type (str), limit (int))
```

... And so on.

Now this works:

```
  var feeds = [
    {"groupName":"News",
     "0": [
       {"url":"http://xkcd.com/rss.xml","type":"mixed","limit": 8},
       {"url":"http://xkcd.com/rss.xml","type":"photo","limit": 4}
     ],
     "1": [
       {"url":"http://xkcd.com/rss.xml","type":"mixed","limit": 8},
       {"url":"http://xkcd.com/rss.xml","type":"mixed","limit": 8},
       {"url":"http://xkcd.com/rss.xml","type":"photo","limit": 4}
     ]
    },
    {"groupName":"Comics",
     "0": [
       {"url":"http://xkcd.com/rss.xml","type":"photo","limit": 8},
       {"url":"http://superphazed.tumblr.com/rss","type":"photo","limit": 8}
     ]
    }
  ];
```

But

1. I want to avoid maintaining a numerical index for the column keys ;
2. I'm not sure it's the right data structure type.

Apparently the form above is a JavaScript literal object, that is, not an array and not JSon. This is a problem, I want to use the right data structure for what I intend to do with it : At one point in time, I need to validate variables against this data structure, that is to say "OK, this variable is a proper list of feeds". I also need to easily add, delete and rename elements, and from what I can see, there are [at least 3 approaches](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty#See_also) to "arrays" in JavaScript, each with its own set of idiosyncrasies, methods and tools, dos and don'ts ; The context is JavaScript (module pattern) in the browser, and JQuery `is` available.

So I guess my question is twofold:

- What is the best data structure in this context to allow easy manipulation later ;
- Is there a way to have unnamed columns containing non-indexed feeds?

Comment: Is there some reason you don't just want to add a `columns` property to the group entity and use a real array there? `feeds = { groupName: "News", columns: [ [ {url, type, limit } ], [ {url, type, limit} ] ] }`

Comment: @Gerrit0 Hi ; No, no reason, I just need it to work, for now this structure seems to disagree with JSlint: 1-He doesn't want elements with only values and no key, and 2-It says `duplicate key: 'groupName'` and BTW I'm having a hard time understanding this one: Duplicate *key*? Of course I want to duplicate *keys*..? I must be missing something *big*, thanks a lot for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to label object fields `0` or `1`. On each Tab, you could have a field columns which is an array, of arrays containing the feeds in the column as so:

```
const Tabs = [
  {
    groupName: "News"
    columns: [
      [
        {"url":"http://xkcd.com/rss.xml","type":"mixed","limit": 8},
        {"url":"http://xkcd.com/rss.xml","type":"photo","limit": 4}
      ],
      [
        {"url":"http://xkcd.com/rss.xml","type":"mixed","limit": 8},
        {"url":"http://xkcd.com/rss.xml","type":"mixed","limit": 8},
        {"url":"http://xkcd.com/rss.xml","type":"photo","limit": 4}
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    groupName: "Comics",
    columns: [
      [
        {"url":"http://xkcd.com/rss.xml","type":"photo","limit": 8},
        {"url":"http://superphazed.tumblr.com/rss","type":"photo","limit": 8}
      ]
    ]
  }
];
```